# Highcharts Symbol in Legend

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a highcharts legend where the symbols are displaying with varying sizes as they are different sizes in the actual chart. Unfortunately, when the sizes of the data points grow, they also grow in the legend. I want the legend symbols to remain the same size regardless of the data point size.

Here is an example where the data points have grown with the graph. In case it matters, the actual graph I'm using is a scatter plot (unlike the example).

http://jsfiddle.net/RsUhk/

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: personally I cant see this happening though the line                 marker: {radius: 20 } is why they are so big...

Comment: I'm hoping to find a way to have the marker be one size while the legend marker stays at the standard radius: 5 - or whatever the default is.

Answer (score 8):

This is a little hacky but it's the best I can come up with.  After you draw the plot, manually adjust the legend symbols:

```
$(chart.series).each(function(){
    this.legendSymbol.attr('width',8);
    this.legendSymbol.attr('height',8);
    this.legendSymbol.attr('x',this.legendLine.attr('translateX')-17);
    this.legendSymbol.attr('y',this.legendLine.attr('translateY')-4);
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SAYRC/).

Comment: Thanks a ton. Hacky or not, I need it to play nicely and this the trick.

Comment: I used this example from HighCharts as it closely resembled my situation minus the fact that I'm using a scatter graph (not a line). As a result, legendLine doesn't exist. I've tried using something like this. 


      this.legendSymbol.translate(-10,-10).attr({height:10, width:10});

Unfortunately, the positioning is off. I'm not sure how to successfully reposition based on the new dimensions. Thoughts Mark?

Comment: One more note: The legendSymbols size are dynamically assigned and are almost guaranteed to be different in size.