# Highcharts: Make the legend symbol a square or rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am trying to Make the legend symbol a square or rectangle for a line graph. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n3h2totc/)

[image]

The line is fine. I dont want change the line width.
HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            symbolHeight:100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

I tried adding symbolHeight in legend. But its not working.

```
legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            symbolHeight:100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
```

How to increase the height of line symbol to make it rectangle or square?

Comment: See the similiar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859766/highcharts-legend-symbol-sizes-for-scatter-charts / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551727/highcharts-symbol-in-legend

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have tried these. But I have updated the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a fake series as follows and provider marker to it.

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'line',
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',

        //borderWidth: 0
    },

    series: [{

        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        showInLegend : false,


        marker:{enabled:false}

    },{
        name : "testing",
        data : {},
        marker : {symbol : 'square',radius : 12 }
    }
            ]
});
});
```

Working demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anchika/gb32bx2j/1/)

Comment: How to make it a circle ?

Answer (score 28):

It's possible to achieve square legend symbols via configuration. Just set [`legend.symbolRadius`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolRadius) value to `0`.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9bzy2qzq/

Comment: Your demo contains a column chart, but a solution for a line chart is asked. When changing type to "line" it clearly doesnt work.

Comment: I appreciate it ! :) Thank you

Answer (score 12):

This is a copy of the question: [How to access legendSymbols and change their shape in HighCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812476/how-to-access-legendsymbols-and-change-their-shape-in-highcharts)

It has a similar answer and two others:

**First Option:**

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = 
Highcharts.seriesTypes.area.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
```

**Second Option:**

You can change the `stroke-width` attribute on the path element.

We can provide functions to Highcharts that will be drawn whenever the chart is drawn. Since `redraw` is not called on the first drawing the `load` event is needed

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () { 
            $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
        },
        redraw: function () {
            $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

All answers are correct but I found a pretty hack method. Replacing legend rectangle symbol with square:

```
legend: {
   symbolHeight: 12,
   symbolWidth: 12,
   symbolRadius: 6
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/symbolradius/)

Comment: This does not work for line charts, as specified in the question

Answer (score 4):

For rectangular legend we need to set `squareSymbol: false`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
       type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
       text: 'Round legend symbols'
    },

    xAxis: {
       categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
    },

    legend: {
       symbolWidth: 16,
       symbolRadius: 0,
       squareSymbol: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }, {
        data: [6, 4, 5, 3]
    }, {
        data: [2, 7, 6, 5]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: The question was for a line graph. If you change the type to 'line' instead of 'column', it will not work anymore.

Comment: Yes! - this helped my to get rectangular symbols. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Highcharts 5 introduced *styled mode*, you can easily find the symbol elements, and change their attributes. To make the symbol square:

```
$(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width',16);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3h2totc/23/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a round symbol, you can use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kL5sghrx/3/

```html
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function(){            
  $( ".highcharts-legend-item path" ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this)
   .attr('d','M10.1,15.3L10.1,15.3c-3,0-5.5-2.5-5.5-5.5v0c0-3,2.5-5.5,5.5-5.5h0c3,0,5.5,2.5,5.5,5.5v0 C15.6,12.8,13.2,15.3,10.1,15.3z')
   .attr('fill', $( this ).attr('stroke'))
   .attr('stroke-dasharray','0,0'); 
  });
         },
      redraw: function(){            
  $( ".highcharts-legend-item path" ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this)
   .attr('d','M10.1,15.3L10.1,15.3c-3,0-5.5-2.5-5.5-5.5v0c0-3,2.5-5.5,5.5-5.5h0c3,0,5.5,2.5,5.5,5.5v0 C15.6,12.8,13.2,15.3,10.1,15.3z')
   .attr('fill', $( this ).attr('stroke'))
   .attr('stroke-dasharray','0,0'); 
  });
        }
    },
 }
```

Comment: I received this from the HighSoft support guys:

If you enable markers for line charts, you will see that the legend items will also change. As a workaround you could overwrite line markers with column markers too. Take a look at both example below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker

Examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/j53pbxb1/ - markers enabled
http://jsfiddle.net/q4Lrabpx/ - markers from column series

`Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;`