# How to set highchart legend style?

Tags: highcharts

I made a jsfiddle example to demo this.
http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/ttxvpduv/.

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            name:'a',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },
                {
            name:'b',
                    type:'area',
            data: [129.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

In my example, I have two series (one line, one area). We can see that the legend for line chart is a line, and the legend area is bigger (like an area).

Is there a way to make all legends a line or some style?

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to use "fake" serie like in the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510810/highcharts-make-the-legend-symbol-a-square-or-rectangle/27535466#27535466

Comment: Saw that example, but how can I make the fake series to show at bottom other than right? All our legends need to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky (maybe I've just been using d3.js too much lately) but you could modify the SVG on the fly:

```
, function(chart){
    // remove the line and rect
    $('.highcharts-legend-item path, .highcharts-legend-item rect').remove();
    // add in your own elements
    $('.highcharts-legend-item').each(function(i, obj){
        var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        $(circle).attr({"r":10,"fill":"red", "cy": 10});
        $(obj).append(circle);
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttxvpduv/1/).

Answer (score 1):

worked out this now.

see http://jsfiddle.net/ttxvpduv/2/

```
   Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = 
     Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
```