# Highcharts -> how to add vertical title to bar? how to make the symbol in the legend a rectangle?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, titlebar, legend-properties

```
`https://codepen.io/martynakil/pen/BawpPJv`
```

how to add vertical title to bar? how to make the symbol in the legend a rectangle?

I need:

1. title vertical
2. symbol a reactangle
3. a vertical line that separates the negative value from the positive value

THANK YOU!

here screenshot [screenshot]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAcVo.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use data labels:

---

```
  series: [{
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        align: 'left',
        inside: true,
        rotation: -90,
        x: -20,
        y: -10
      },
      name: "John",
      data: [{
        dataLabels: {
          format: 'Apples'
        },
        y: 5
      }, ...]
    },
    ...
  ]
```

2. [Highcharts: Make the legend symbol a square or rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510810/highcharts-make-the-legend-symbol-a-square-or-rectangle)
3. Use plotlines:

---

```
  yAxis: {
    ...,
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      zIndex: 4
    }]
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hfamwetg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels